# what's the meaning of "mountain masses"

Tags: meaning

what's the meaning of "mountain masses"

Their [travelers and geographers] task was by no means an easy one, for the 
**mountain masses** and mountain chains of the [Haemus] peninsula do not 
constitute a regular, well-defined system

Comment: It's interesting that you're unsure about the meaning of "mountain masses", but not "mountain chains". I think we can understand a "mountain mass" by using the definitions of *mountain* and *mass*. For example, Macmillan Dictionary defines [mass](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/mass) (sense 2) as "a lump or amount of a substance that does not have a clear or definite shape".

Answer (score 2):

A [mountain mass](http://www.answers.com/topic/mountain-mass), also known as [massif](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/massif) is an irregular grouping of mountains, which lacks the broad linear sweep of a range or chain.

Answer (score 1):

It's a technical term used to define [isostasy](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/ISOSTASY) and the root zone of mountain chain.

See the picture here -

[image]

The [description](http://quran-errors.blogspot.in/2013/10/requran-scientific-error-mountains-as.html) there reads...

> Isostacy: **mountain masses** deflect a pendulum away from the vertical, but not as much as might be expected. In the diagram, the vertical position is shown by (a); if the mountain were simply a load resting on a uniform crust, it ought to be deflected to (c). However because it has a deep of relatively non-dense rocks, the observed deflection is only to (b). *Picture courtesy of Building Planet Earth, Cattermole pg. 35*

Having this said, their task was not easy as the mountains weren't regular and even. Mountains with such shape require a lot of strength to climb and pass.

The [story defines further hardship](http://travel.yodelout.com/turkey-in-europe-general-aspects/) after your sentence in concern -

> There is no central range, with spurs running out on both sides, and gradually decreasing in height as they approach the plains. Nor is the centre of the peninsula its most elevated portion, for the culminating summits are dispersed over the country apparently without order.